# Unexpected meta character at xsd pattern

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, metacharacters

I have a pattern in an xsd file to check a json value in an xml file is valid for my system. I am getting an unexpected meta character error when i run the validation stage. I checked meta characters but, i couldn't see the meta character that causes error. Any idea what is wrong?

NOTE : in original pattern i use **&quot**; for **"**

So here my regex :

```
\{(\s*"*[a-z]+"\s*:\s*"[^"]*("\s*,)?)*"\s*\}
```

Comment: Your pattern is correct. Regex statement is not the reason of your error. Please share screenshot of the error.

Comment: You should also tell us which schema processor you are using. Some of them (notably Microsoft's) use their own regex dialect rather than the one defined in the W3C XSD specifications.

Comment: Here the explanation : i edited my regex before asked that question to be clear. I used ? After * with intend of making some inner patterns non greedy but i did not know that there is not sth like that in xml schema patterns so when i delete them(to be clear) it did not produce error. I asked question and fatihn recognized it has not error. So i am also recognized source of error after answer.